# Как выводить дату текущую в таком формате 2020-10-29?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, дата

Мой пример вывод даты

```
beforeDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this.interval)
    },
    created() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.date = new Date()
        }, 1000);

    }
```

template

```
<b-col class="font-weight-bold time-title">{{date | date('time')}}</b-col>
<b-col class="data-title">{{date | date('date')}}</b-col>
```

Функция експорт

```
export default function dateFilter(value, format= 'datetime') {
// console.log(value);
const options = {}

if (format.includes('date')) {
    options.day = 'numeric'
    options.month = '2-digit'
    options.year = 'numeric'
}

if (format.includes('time')) {
    options.hour = '2-digit'
    options.minute = '2-digit'
    // options.second = '2-digit'
}
return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('uk-UK', options).format(new Date(value))
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Вся логика работы `Intl.DateTimeFormat` хорошо описана в [документации mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) и [learn javascript](https://learn.javascript.ru/intl). Что касается форматирования, то это объемный процесс с настройкой [Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.format](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format). Если вы не хотите углубляться в тонкости настройки и просто работать с датами, то воспользуйтесь пакетом [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).

Использование фильтров в [Vue 3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html) имеет статус [deprecated](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0015-remove-filters.md), для многих момент спорный, но если планируется миграция, то переносите всё в функции хэлперы уже сейчас:

```js
import formatDate from './filter/formatDate';

setup () {
  // тут логика компонента
  return {
    formatDate, // далее в темплейте просто использовать как метод
  }
}
```