# Конвертировать дату в правильный вид

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста как конвертировать дату с временем `2020-10-30 14:07:03` в вид типа `30.10.2020 14:07:03`

Comment: для этого есть отличная библиотека MomentJs:
https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Был [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1197496/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-2020-10-29/1197590#1197590), лучше воспользуйтесь пакетом [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ребята, какие библиотеки? Зачем столько кода? Для конкретной задачи, [всё придумали](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) до нас.

```js
// Как конвертировать дату с временем 2020-10-30 14:07:03 
//                         в вид типа 30.10.2020 14:07:03

var date = new Date('2020-10-30 14:07:03');
console.log(date.toLocaleString('ru-RU').replace(',', ''));
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте воспользоваться этим кодом:

```js
const formatDate = (date) => {
  // получаем строку даты и времени
  const [dateStr, timeStr] = date.split(' ');

  const d = new Date(dateStr);

  // прибавляем единицу, потому что отсчет месяцев начинается с 0
  let month = `${d.getMonth() + 1}`;
  let day = `${d.getDate()}`;
  let year = `${d.getFullYear()}`;

  if (month.length < 2) {
    month = `0${month}`;
  }
  if (day.length < 2) {
    day = `0${day}`;
  }

  return `${[day, month, year].join('.')} ${timeStr}`;
};

console.log(formatDate('2020-10-30 14:07:03'));
```